# How do you calculate all the common tangents given two fixed circles and draw an image?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, graphics, geometry

The two fixed circle equations given are known to be:

```
x^2 + y^2 == 1
(x - 3)^2 + (y - 4)^2 == 16
```

By calculating that they have three common tangents

```
x==-1
5-3x-4y==0
25-7x+24y==0
```

Is there any way to calculate in Mathematica the tangent equations of the above two fixed circles and draw an image of the two circles and all the tangents?

Comment: Similar to [57983](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57983/how-can-i-only-draw-outer-common-tangent-to-two-circles).

Comment: Related [How to make a Line with no end?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10669/how-to-make-a-line-with-no-end)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the tangents aren't "male." Are you translating from some other language?

Comment: @Michael E2,Chinese

Comment: common tangents

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- The tangent line of the circle `Circle[center,r]` through the point `{a,b}` on circle and perpendicular to the direction `{a,b}-center`,so we set the tangent line to be

```
InfiniteLine[{a,b}, 
      RotationMatrix[π/2] . ({a, b} - center)]
```

- We use `RegionEqual` to determint the common tangent lines, that is, if two tangent lines are coincident straight lines, then such two lines  build a common tangent line.

```
Clear[c1, r1, c2, r2];
c1 = {0, 0};
r1 = 1;
c2 = {3, 4};
r2 = 4;
sol = Solve[{RegionEqual[
     InfiniteLine[{a1, b1}, 
      RotationMatrix[π/2] . ({a1, b1} - c1)], 
     InfiniteLine[{a2, b2}, 
      RotationMatrix[π/2] . ({a2, b2} - c2)]], {a1, 
      b1} ∈ Circle[c1, r1], {a2, b2} ∈ 
     Circle[c2, r2]}, {a1, b1, a2, b2}, Reals];
graphs = 
 Graphics[{Red, Point[{{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}}], Circle[c1, r1], 
      Circle[c2, r2], RandomColor[], AbsoluteThickness[2], 
      InfiniteLine[{a1, b1}, 
       RotationMatrix[π/2] . ({a1, b1} - c1)], , 
      InfiniteLine[{a2, b2}, 
       RotationMatrix[π/2] . ({a2, b2} - c2)]}] /. # & /@ sol
Show[graphs, Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.05}]]
```

[image]

[image]

- Convert the lines to the implicit form.

```
RegionConvert[
     InfiniteLine[{a1, b1}, 
       RotationMatrix[π/2] . ({a1, b1} - c1)] /. #, 
     "Implicit"][[1]] /. {\[FormalX] -> x, \[FormalY] -> y} & /@ sol
```

> `{1 + x == 0, 7 x == 25 + 24 y, 3 x + 4 y == 5}`

- Test random circles.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
tangentLines[{{x1_, y1_}, r1_}, {{x2_, y2_}, r2_}] := 
 Module[{sol, graph},
  sol = Solve[{RegionEqual[
       InfiniteLine[{a1, b1}, 
        RotationMatrix[π/2] . ({a1, b1} - {x1, y1})], 
       InfiniteLine[{a2, b2}, 
        RotationMatrix[π/2] . ({a2, b2} - {x2, y2})]], {a1, 
        b1} ∈ Circle[{x1, y1}, r1], {a2, b2} ∈ 
       Circle[{x2, y2}, r2]} // Rationalize[#, 0] &, {a1, b1, a2, b2},
     Reals];
  If[sol=={}, 
   Graphics[{Red, Circle[{x1, y1}, r1], Circle[{x2, y2}, r2]}], 
   Graphics[{Red, Point[{{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}}], Circle[{x1, y1}, r1], 
        Circle[{x2, y2}, r2], RandomColor[], AbsoluteThickness[2], 
        InfiniteLine[{a1, b1}, 
         RotationMatrix[π/2] . ({a1, b1} - {x1, y1})], , 
        InfiniteLine[{a2, b2}, 
         RotationMatrix[π/2] . ({a2, b2} - {x2, y2})]}] /. # & /@ 
    sol]]
SeedRandom[1];
ListAnimate[Table[({x1, y1} = RandomReal[{-4, 4}, 2];
   {x2, y2} = RandomReal[{-4, 4}, 2];
   r1 = RandomReal[{0, 4}];
   r2 = RandomReal[{0, 4}];
   tangentLines[{{x1, y1}, r1}, {{x2, y2}, r2}] // 
    Show[#, Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.05}]] &), {i, 
   20}], AnimationRate -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: It's really too powerful. Can you add a planar Cartesian coordinate system?

Comment: Can coordinate arrows be added?

Comment: Does this code adapt to any two circles finding their male tangents?

Comment: Can you add arrows to the right and up of the x-axis and y-axis respectively?

Comment: @csn899  Yes, we can change the value of `c1, r1, c2, r2`  for any two circles.

Comment: Can you calculate and display the straight-line equations for all the common tangents?

Comment: Thank you very much! This feature is so useful!

Comment: The code of  random circles.Can this code add dynamic common tangent equation?

Comment: @csn899  Yes,it is easy done, but I think it make the pictures too complex.

Comment: The line equation can be displayed in the upper right corner of the picture, and the corresponding line and equation are represented in the same color.

Answer (score 4):

This solution is a little bit... elaborate for the task, but shows how one can use `GeometricTest` to find solutions using synthetic geometry tools:

```
With[
  {c1 = {0, 0}, r1 = 1,
   c2 = {3, 4}, r2 = 4,
   pts = {p1 -> {x1, y1}, p2 -> {x2, y2}, v -> {vx, vy}}},
  With[{sol =
     Solve[
      {(* Point p1 lies on first circle, and the circle and line
          passing through this point to the direction v are tangent. *)
        GeometricTest[
         {CircleThrough[{p1}, c1, r1],
          InfiniteLine[p1, v]},
         "Tangent"],
        (* Point p2 lies on second circle, and the circle and line
           passing through this point to the direction v are tangent. *)
        GeometricTest[
         {CircleThrough[{p2}, c2, r2],
          InfiniteLine[p2, v]},
         "Tangent"],
        (* Point p2 is on the line *)
        (* This is actually a workaround for bug in RegionMember
           with a non-constant InfiniteLine. *)
        Quiet@RegionDistance[InfiniteLine[p1, v], p2] == 0,
        (* v is of unit length *)
        Norm[v] == 1,
        (* Prevent finding mirror images of v. *)
        vx > 0 || (vx == 0 && vy > 0)} /. pts,
      Flatten[{p1, p2, v} /. pts], Reals]},
   Graphics[
       {Circle[c1, r1], Circle[c2, r2],
         InfiniteLine[p1, v],
         PointSize[Medium],
         Point[{p1, p2}],
         With[{off = RotationTransform[50 Degree][v]},
              {Arrow[{# + 2 off, #}], Text[#, # + 3 off]}] & /@
            {p1, p2}} /. pts,
       ImagePadding -> 15,
       Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.05}],
       PlotLabel ->
        (* Solve line equation. *)
        TraditionalForm@Refine[
          RegionMember[
           InfiniteLine[p1, v] /. pts /. #, {x, y}],
          Element[Alternatives[x, y], Reals]]] /. # & /@ sol]] //
 GraphicsRow[#, ImageSize -> 768] &
```

[image]

Comment: ```Show[graphs, Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.05}]```Why didn't I show axes and arrows when I added this?

Comment: This code is also very good. Can the coordinates of the tangent points in each graph be calculated and marked next to the tangent points in each diagram.

Comment: @csn899 Modified a bit to include coordinates...

Comment: Thank you very much! Can this code adapt to any given two fixed circles to find their common tangent and tangent coordinates?

Comment: @csn899 You can try, but I found out that some parts of the `GeometricTest` functionality may be a bit fragile in cases where circles are tangent to each other for tangent line between them. Technically `InfiniteLine` direction vector form is not mentioned in the documentation for this...